# How can I upload my telegram-bot on Haskell to Heroku(or another free servers)?

Tags: heroku, server, telegram, telegram-bot

I wrote telegram-bot on Haskell using the telegram-api library (https://github.com/klappvisor/haskell-telegram-api). It works fine, but I want to upload it to the server so that I do not run it many times. Thanks in advance for your reply)

Comment: Pls add more details so that you can get better help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Haskell  programming question.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard That would be grounds for changing the tags, not for closing. I think Heroku is on-topic for Stack Overflow (tens of thousands of questions).

Comment: VTC removed ...

Answer (score 0):

In principal it is possible.

You need a `Procfile` and an `app.json`.

`Procfile` specifies a CLI command which Heroku is going to execute. In `app.json` you define used environment variables as well as the buildpack you require.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema

You will need the Haskell buildpack. There are many and you will have to pick one. E.g.:

- https://github.com/mfine/heroku-buildpack-stack
- https://github.com/puffnfresh/heroku-buildpack-haskell
- https://github.com/mietek/haskell-on-heroku
- https://github.com/begriffs/heroku-buildpack-ghc
- ...

There is no official Haskell buildpack made by Heroku.

---

It might be worth pursuing the idea of dockerizing your project. Heroku can also deploy Docker containers.

---

With the lack of information you provided all you can do is read through the articles I linked and attempt deploying it. You have not provided any specific errors or problems.